# Insert a (mostly) blank row into an R dataframe for aesthetic purposes (exporting as .csv to LaTeX)

Tags: r, dataframe

**Background:**

I have a little `dataframe` composed of percentage estimates across two `characteristics`. One is "political party", the other is "sex". As it stands, these specific names are unmentioned in the `df` even if the categories that comprise them are. Here it is:

```
d <- data.frame(characteristic = c("Republican","Democrat","Male","Female"), 
                percent = c(45, 55, 70, 30),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

For those without `R` available to them at the moment, here's what that looks like:

[image: what_ive_got]

**The Problem:**

As the result of data analysis, this `df` is perfectly adequate. But because I want to export it is a .csv file and insert it into a report I'm writing, I'd like to make some aesthetic modifications in order to make that integration as smooth as possible. In particular, I'd like to insert 2 blank rows to act as subheadings. In other words, I'm looking to do something like this:

[image: what_id_like]

**What I've tried:**

I feel I'm quite close, because I can get the new rows in using these two lines of code:

```
d[nrow(d) + 1,] = c("Party","")
d[nrow(d) + 1,] = c("Sex","")
```

But that only appends them to the bottom of the dataset and I'm not sure how to move them into the desired positions, or if there a more efficient way to do this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `add_row`:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
        mutate(percent = as.character(percent)) %>%
        add_row(characteristic = "Party", percent = "", .before = 1) %>%
        add_row(characteristic = "Sex", percent = "", .before = 4)
```

Output:

```
  characteristic percent
1          Party        
2     Republican      45
3       Democrat      55
4            Sex        
5           Male      70
6         Female      30
```

Note that the above solution converts `percent` into a character to match your desired output. If you do not care about replacing `""` with `NA`, then you could do:

```
d %>%
        add_row(characteristic = "Party", percent = NA, .before = 1) %>%
        add_row(characteristic = "Sex", percent = NA, .before = 4)
```

Output:

```
  characteristic percent
1          Party      NA
2     Republican      45
3       Democrat      55
4            Sex      NA
5           Male      70
6         Female      30
```

Comment: This is terrific -- that `.before` argument was exactly the thing I found myself hoping existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the OP mentioned, it is aesthestic preference, an option is `kableExtra`.  (Note: This is posted as an alternative way to visualize)

```
library(kableExtra)
kbl(d) %>%
  kable_paper("striped", full_width = FALSE) %>%
  pack_rows("Party", 1, 3) %>%
  pack_rows("Sex", 3, 4)
```

-output

[image]